# PHP issue. Output stops sometimes after a specific echo

Tags: php, echo

I have got an issue that I don't know how to debug. Sometimes the output suddenly stops halfway through a PHP script, after a specific echo.

This is a part of the code. After `someLonJsonString` the output sometimes stops. When the output stops, refreshing the page won't help, so it has something to do with the value also?

```
<div class="ac-calendar-options">
    <div class="timestamp"><?php echo $currentTimestamp;?></div> 
    <div class="someLongJsonString"><?php echo $someLongJsonString;?></div>
    <!-- The output of the script will cut off here -->
    <div class="timezone"><?php echo $timezone;?></div>
</div>
```

Refreshing won't help, but adding some useless echo before the long Json string does help:

```
<div class="ac-calendar-options">
    <div class="timestamp"><?php echo $currentTimestamp;?></div> 
    <div style="display:none"><?php echo "test"; ?></div>
    <div class="someLongJsonString"><?php echo $someLongJsonString;?></div>
    <div class="timezone"><?php echo $timezone;?></div>
</div>
```

When I remove the `fix`, the problem comes back. Above `fix` does fix it for that item, but after a while, it pops up again but for another item with another JSON string.

How can I debug this problem? Even temporarily showing the errors for that page/item does fix the problem. And I just don't understand why a simple echo will temporarily fix the problem.

---

Since we moved to php 7.x from 5.6 this problem magically solved.

Comment: maybe you hitting time limit ? try `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: What's inside the JSON string? What happens if you escape it properly with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Comment: Try looking at the source code in the browser, there may be a hint there somewhere.

Comment: It's very likely to some special characters in your JSON string. Properly escape it or do whatever you need to normalize your output.

Comment: @Peter I will put some escaping in place. Now it is more or less unescaped. I still find it strange why PHP would totally stop with the output then, instead of just messing with the html. Problem occurs once in a week orso, so I have to wait if it happens again.

Comment: @Edgarth Nah, I don't think so. The execution time of the script is within half a second. Some pages take longer to load. And the script always stops on the same line.

Comment: @RaviMattar Changing or updating php might help. It did for us. There probably was a problem with the php installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we moved to php 7.x from 5.6 this problem magically solved. I can't provide any other info I'm afraid, this is just it...