# PHP Stops execution randomly for no reason - random changes in code fixes it

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

On our platform, users may have different combinations of products in their inventory. Every now and then, a user will report to us that the page that lists these products is crashing. What this "crashing" actually is is PHP just stoping the rendering of a product for no reason at all, and then not rendering the rest of the page (for example, PHP won't include the footer file, so the page just ends at the half-rendered product).

Sometimes it stops at a random product after rendering it fully, sometimes it only renders a product's image and stops the whole page rendering there.

Seemingly random changes to the code seem to make the crashing stop. What do I mean?
If I add this anywhere inside the product loop:

`<?php echo "<script>console.log('test');</script>"; ?>`

It will stop the error. Just today I decided turning php.ini's display errors on and that fixed the error for some dude. Turning it off brought it back. Some other user was fixed when I changed the loop's syntax from

`<?php foreach ($inventory as $code) : ?>`

to

```
<?php 
   foreach ($inventory as $code)
   {
```

This is the current code for the loop:

```
<div class="myProductsList">
<?php 
    $inventory = GetUserInventory($user, $plan);
    
    if ($inventory) 
    {
        $evenOdd = false; 
        foreach ($inventory as $code)
        {
            $product = GetProductObject($code, $plan); 
            $product = $product[0]->ID;
            if ($product)
            {
                $prdTitle = get_the_title($product); 
                $prdDate  = get_the_date('F, Y', $product);
                $prdImg   = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product);
                $prdLink  = str_replace('/offer/', '/product/', get_the_permalink($product));

                $evenOdd  = !$evenOdd;
                $tagCloud = get_field("prd_tagcloud", $product);
                $owner = false; 

                include 'parts/product-card.php';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

And this is the current code for the product-card

```
<div class="productCard altCard_<?=$evenOdd;?> <?=$owner;?>" stamp="<?=get_the_date('U', $product);?>">
    <div class="productCardCont fullw fullh cont col">
        <a href="<?=$prdLink;?>">
            <img class="fullw" src="<?=$prdImg;?>"> 
        </a>
        
        <div class="productCardAbout fullw hcent cont col npad">
            <h3 class="fullw fcent"><?=$prdTitle;?></h3>
            <span class="fullw fcent"><?=$prdDate;?></span>
            <div class="productCardWarp"></div>
            <div class="ctaMain cont col hcent" id="#ctaMain">
               <?=ctaMain($prdLink, "Select");?>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <span style="display:none!important;"><?=$tagCloud;?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have absoulutely no idea what causes this, especially since no errors appear when I turn them on, no product has any invalid or corrupted data (as you can see I only pull their images, names and date), no inventory code is ever wrong, we have very few users compared to our VM's specs capabilities, the page always loads blazing fast, and as I said:

Random users, with seemingly nothing in common experience these issues, and the 'fixes' often make no sense at all.

One last thing. Sometimes in order to investigate these error reports, I will copy the user's inventory and set it to my own test account (so we both have a identical inventory). Sometimes my account experiences the error, sometimes it doesn't.

**The "inventory" I talk about** is a table in our database, where each user has a row, and the inventory is just a comma separeated sequence of our internal codes for each products. The codes are a simple number-letter combination.

Example of a inventory that has caused my account to crash:

`F2112S04E6B,F2105S03E05,FL21M03V2,F2106S03E06,F2107S04E01,FL20M03V1,F2109S04E03,F2110S04E04,F2111S04E05,F2202S05E02,F2006S1E00,F2208S06E02,F2209S06E03,`

Sometimes, if I remove a random product from it, it stops crashing.

PHP version: PHP 8.0.18
Database: 10.6.7-MariaDB

I'm running on a **Bitnami Wordpress** stack

---

**The question: What is causing this error?**
I know it's a complex environment and many things could be at fault, but looking at the code I provided, is anything there that looks potentially guilty?

If the error that I have described is not clear enough, please bare with me as this is a very unique situation which I have never encountered, and I will do my best to make it clearer for you.

---

EDIT

Tim Morton raised some relevant topics in the comments, so I'll reply to them here to improve context for this question.

*'Your first "fix" was to print a javascript command?'*

- I printed multiple JS commands (console.log) just to see at what point in the PHP script it crashed. When I ran it I noticed that the simple presence of these console.log commands, for some bizarre reason, fixed the crash itself.

*'Then changed the syntax of your loop? This seems aimless.'*

- Yes, and yes it does seem aimless, but believe me it worked. That's why I'm dumbfounded, since it shouldn't.

*'Is it printing all of the php-generated content and then failing some javascript?'*

- No, there is no Javascript here. The only JS was added later (console.log), as I explained, in order to see at what point the PHP crashed. It usually prints the PHP generated product-card.php (included by the loop) and at a random product, stops printing anything, even outside the loop.

*'or is it failing in one particular part of the php loop?'*

- I'm pretty sure its in the PHP loop, but I have not been able to narrow it down.

*'To diagnose, you could use try/catch and error_log() to help narrow it down to what is actually failing.'*

- Will do! The issue is, simply adding a try/catch will probably 'fix it' since as I stated earlier, random changes to the code seem to 'fix' the issue temporarily.

*'Does the same record fail every time (hint, it could be the next record that's actually failing)'*

- So far it seems random. I've tried modifying the inventory record to place different products at different orders. This sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. So far no pattern emerged.

---

**UPDATE**

So far, I've noticed two types of crashes. One of them it prints out halfway thru on a product-card.php iteration, then crashes (so it doesn't even get to the other iterations). On one of these cases, it crashed at only the second iteration.

On this specific case I've been able to see the front end code thru Chrome dev tools, and I noticed that it crashed right here, at the product-card.php

`<a href="https://some-link.com/something/`

As you can see, it crashed right after the echo, as it didn't even put the finishing quote and '>'.

On the other type of crash, it'd crash at a random iteration too, only the last iteration it'd finish rendering whatever card it was on and then crash, instead of crashing halfway thru.

---

I saw people commenting that I should just update or modify my PHP installation and be done with it, and to be honest I may do that since this is happening in prod, but this question is aimed at why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the server logs - maybe something is throwing an error in the logs that can help. Also perhaps the database is causing this somehow. Where or how are you hosting - maybe check some logs on the hosting platform. Its hard to know for sure what it is but just some thoughts on where to look.

Comment: I am suspecting Php short tag `<?=` could cause an issue if you have not enabled it on `php.ini`

Comment: Don't confuse the php short echo `<?=` with the long deprecated short open tag `<?`.  The short echo is widely used and very likely to remain.  It, as well as the looping syntax mentioned earlier `<?php foreach ($inventory as $code) : ?>` are well suited for use in views (templates).

Comment: Your first "fix" was to print a javascript command?  Then changed the syntax of your loop?  This seems aimless.  Is it printing all of the php-generated content and then failing some javascript?  or is it failing in one particular part of the php loop?  To diagnose, you could use try/catch and error_log() to help narrow it down to what is actually failing.  Does the same record fail every time (hint, it could be the *next* record that's actually failing).

Comment: A couple of strong suggestions: 1) look at your web server error log. It may help you understand why your page code crashes sometimes. On many UNIX-like OSs it's at `var/logs/apache2/error.log`  2) try editing your php.ini file to increase `memory_limit`. This problem's randomness smells to me like heap exhaustion (running out of memory). You're probably right on the edge of running out of memory; increasing `memory_limit` by 1.5 or 2.0 times its present size should be a good thing to try.

Comment: @O.Jones As per php.ini: ```memory_limit = 512M``` and ```report_memleaks = On```
- Both of those values are the same as per phpinfo()
 - 
PHP's error log shows no fatal errors nor any memory related error
 - 
Outside the loop I put a 
```echo "<script>console.log('mem: " . memory_get_usage(true) . "');</script>";```
And the value was less than 10 megabytes

Comment: php's error log is not the same thing as the web server's error log. What that log? Does it contain anything of interest.

Comment: I think PHP is logging to Apache's. I haven't been able to find PHP's own log, phpinfo() ```error_log``` option is empty and the files are 0B in size at ```/opt/bitnami/php/logs/php-fpm.log```

Comment: Whenever I have had an error without a message it is because the exception handler itself has an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039674/php-issue-output-stops-sometimes-after-a-specific-echo
I believe this issue is very similar to mine. Only I can't just update PHP and hope for it to fix it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, once it fails, it keeps failing? Refreshing the page does not work?

Comment: Rarely a simple refresh will fix it, but most times it won't

Comment: I think you've clearly demonstrated that the code you've posted is not to blame, because it is not repeatable (not failing in the same place with the same data).  It's possible that something before this code is using up all your resources, or it's something to do with the OS/box you're hosting it on.  I would honestly do a reboot and maybe a reinstall of PHP.  It's amazing how many things are fixed with a reboot! 
 FWIW, there really should be an error logged *somewhere*...  and once you find it you'll probably do a facepalm ;)

Comment: Appreciate the comment, Tim. Since the bug first started, multiple reboots have happened but still the error persisted. I even upgraded the instance this runs on once, to something with perhaps three times the resources as before. But I think you're right, perhaps I'll have to just reinstall some stuff (maybe just PHP, or Apache, or everything). I'll keep digging for a log reporting this, any tips on where I could find it?

Comment: does it happen with php.ini `opcode.jit=disable` ?

Comment: You are passing $parameters to the function without checking if they are set or not, this could cause a fatal error and top PHP script from running, this happened to me too, i believe that you turned off the display of errors in your php.ini, that's why you are not seeing any errors.

Comment: I would try to catch the issue with `register_shutdown_function` and `error_get_last` by writing a log with unexpected shutdowns (E_ERROR AND E_*_ERROR).

Comment: Can you check for a segfault ? Segfaults are usually visible in your syslog file at /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages and are log messages that contain the word "segfault".

Comment: @WardNsour as I explained previously, the display of errors are disabled because this is production environment. And the one time I managed to reproduce this bug I proceeded to turn on error display, and when I refreshed the bug was gone. Regardless I don't believe there would be an error anyway, since it doesn't appear in the error log.

Comment: @Simon checked, and no ```segfault``` I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very exhaustive wild-goose chase, I've come to the conclusion to the (likely) root cause of the issue:

### Too many errors and warnings being logged onto the `apache2/error.log` file.

Seriously, it was like **hundreds** of warning logs **per second**, the file was several GBs large. I don't know exactly why it caused this behaviour, but **turning off the logging for everything** but critical errors seemed to **solve the issue** AFAIK (we didn't do anything else, it's AFAIK because we can't be 100% sure that this completely stopped for all our users).

Maybe it was a problem with the exception handler itself, as previously suggested. Maybe it were just too many exceptions to handle, maybe PHP or Apache were overwhelmed with so many logs. We'll never know.

*Thank you for everyone who helped, commented and answered, definetely pointed me into the right direction. I were so desperate that I even bountied this, I think. Hopefully this will help another clueless developer out there.*

Comment: With PHP 8.0 the error logs are massively inflated because missing array keys are now WARNING errors rather than simply notices. For our work which deals extensively with fluid arrays and especially SESSION data this greatly inflates error logging when only warnings and above are recorded.

Comment: re: several GB error log files, somewhere you can set the maximum size of error files (php.ini or possibly a SAPI setting?). This may be a good thing to do in-case the issue is exacerbated by loading and writing to very large files. Also look into increasing the RAM on your server.

Answer (score 1):

What does contains `$prdLink` ?
What does contains `$prdImg` ?
What does contains `$prdTitle` ?

Are those variables correct sanitized ?
Does contains chars like `"`, `'`, `>` or anything that could ruins your dom ?

PS. If does, I'm afraid you have bigger problem, a security problem (XSS, etc).

Comment: They are all correctly sanitized nor do they contain such unsafe chars. As you can see they are outputed by Wordpress itself. But yeah I checked where WP gets it from and its safe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's a typo made on this post or you copy pasted it but
`<a href="https://some-link.com/something/` notice you are missing a `"` (sorry to not comment but not enough karma)

Comment: Not a typo. That is precisely what PHP outputed, and thats exactly my point, the ```"``` is missing, because the last command PHP executed was an ```echo``` that printed ```https://some-link.com/something/```